# How to convert pretty format json file into a simple single line json file using java?

Tags: java, json, string

I need to conver Pretty format json file into a single line json file. But unable to do so. Can anyone help me on this?

Example: the below needs to be converted

```
[
 {
  "Employee ID": 1,
  "Name": "Abhishek",
  "Designation": "Software Engineer"
 },
 {
  "Employee ID": 2,
  "Name": "Garima",
  "Designation": "Email Marketing Specialist"
 }
]
[
   {
      "Employee ID": 1,
      "Name": "Abhishek",
      "Designation": "Software Engineer"
   },
   {
      "Employee ID": 2,
      "Name": "Garima",
      "Designation": "Email Marketing Specialist"
   }
]
```

to this:

```
 '[{"Employee ID":1,"Name":"Abhishek","Designation":"Software Engineer"},' \ 
            '{"Employee ID":2,"Name":"Garima","Designation":"Email Marketing Specialist"}]'
```

Comment: If you really need to get the result file, but not the entire text in the memory, I wouldn't use the receipts below, but just read the original file line by line, make a trim and write the result string to the output file:  try (BufferedWriter/FileWiter output = ...; Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName))) { stream.forEach( /* trim and write the result string into output}}. Store only what is really required to make your job, save your resources :)

Comment: Makes sense, Thankyou! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A better and more complete version of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66238651/8430155) with proper error handling and removal of extra spaces.

One problem of the referred answer is that it uses `.concat()` without `.trim()` - a very deeply nested pretty-JSON's indents will be visible as extra spaces in final output.

```
String unprettyJSON = null;

try {
    unprettyJSON = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("pretty.json"))
                        .stream()
                        .map(String::trim)
                        .reduce(String::concat)
                        .orElseThrow(FileNotFoundException::new);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Output with trim:

```
[{"Employee ID": 1,"Name": "Abhishek","Designation": "Software Engineer"},{"Employee ID": 2,"Name": "Garima","Designation": "Email Marketing Specialist"}][{"Employee ID": 1,"Name": "Abhishek","Designation": "Software Engineer"},{"Employee ID": 2,"Name": "Garima","Designation": "Email Marketing Specialist"}]
```

Output without trim:

```
[ {  "Employee ID": 1,  "Name": "Abhishek",  "Designation": "Software Engineer" }, {  "Employee ID": 2,  "Name": "Garima",  "Designation": "Email Marketing Specialist" }][   {      "Employee ID": 1,      "Name": "Abhishek",      "Designation": "Software Engineer"   },   {      "Employee ID": 2,      "Name": "Garima",      "Designation": "Email Marketing Specialist"   }]
```

Comment: Domenico Sibilio and Harshal Parekh it worked as expected, thanks!!

Comment: Hi @Harshal Parekh , it is working as expected but my json is very large, any way to make process fat, it is taking some time for me

Answer (score 2):

If you read the file contents via `Files.readAllLines(Path)` then you already get each line as a different item in a list, which you can in turn merge together into a single line.

For example:

```java
String oneLine = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("input.json"))
.stream()
.reduce(String::concat)
.orElseThrow();

System.out.println(oneLine);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
    unprettyJSON = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("pretty.json"))
                        .stream()
                        .map(String::trim)
                        .reduce(String::concat)
                        .orElseThrow(FileNotFoundException::new);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This above solution works nicely. Thanks for posting it. You can read from a .json file which converts to a single line string which can be also used to POST https requests.

Answer (score 0):

im using sed for this

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n//g' demo.json
```

this would basically change each new line to be the same line.
hope it helped :)